# Missing formdata in angular

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass values from angular to a web api.

Currently what I have for angular which does communicate with the webapi since I have it counting when something connects to it.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("x", "1");
data.append("y", "2");
$scope.http({ method: 'PUT', url: urltowebapi, data: data });
```

What I have on the webapi side is supposed to read the values but it always comes back as `{}`.

```
HttpContent req = Request.Content;
string str = req.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Web API, why are you reading content directly from the `Request` rather than using JSON serialization to pass the data to your controller?

Comment: Attempting to throw everything I could think of at the wall and see what would work. I've been staring at this all day and kind of gave up logic awhile ago.

Comment: The web api is going to come in through a controller. Could you post the code for it please?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I got it.

In angluar I am passing the data.

```
$scope.http({ method: 'PUT', url: controllerurl, data: { data: data } });
```

And in my controller I read it and deserialize the json. I think it was how I had the angular passing the data before but I don't know.

```
HttpContent req = Request.Content;
string str = req.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
string data= jObj["data"].ToString();
```